# CUPS doesn't count the copies of documents

Tags: linux, windows, cups, printer

I have a Samsung ML-5515DN connected via usb to a Debian 8 pc, with CUPS installed. This pc works like a printer server and I have connected to it a Windows 7 pc. 
In windows I have configured the printer with this address: http://PC_IP/printers/NAME_OF_QUEUE. 
For the drivers (windows and linux side) I have used the drivers provided in the printer box. Everything goes good exept for the fact that CUPS doesn't count correctly the copy-per-page of the documents that I send from Windows.

For example if I send 10 copies of 1 page, in the CUPS page_log file I see, for that document, 1 page and 1 copy.

In Linux instead, everything goes good.
I need the copies count because I have set up a limit of copies-per-page.

Have you any ideas to solve this problem?